# Japanese for Vegan & Vegetarians

Tags: word-choice

Based on this description below:

*Vegetarians do not eat meat, fish, or poultry. Vegans, in addition to being vegetarian, do not use other animal products and by-products such as eggs, dairy products, honey, leather, fur, silk, wool, cosmetics, and soaps derived from animal products.*

The word for vegetarian which I know of is : 菜食主義者 
Is there any word to described Vegans in Japanese as described above?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40385/5010

Comment: ベジタリアン, its meaning is the same as 菜食主義者.

Comment: Aslo relevant: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25330/how-to-ask-whether-a-dish-is-pescetarian-friendly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The concept of veganism is scarcely recognized in Japan. When you really have to refer to it, you may use ヴィーガン/[ヴィーガニズム](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AC%E3%83%8B%E3%82%BA%E3%83%A0), followed by its explanation. Some people seem to use words like 絶対菜食主義 or 完全菜食主義, but these are not widely recognized, either. Apparently most Japanese articles regarding veganism primarily use ヴィーガニズム, and optionally introduce 絶対菜食主義/完全菜食主義 as a possible translation. At any rate, you probably have to explain what this word means.

Weblio defines it as 完全菜食主義. ALC defines veganism descriptively as:

> veganism: 【名】〔動物性食物を一切拒否する〕厳格な菜食主義